# Unable to pass the following rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec, jruby

```
class Admins::Setting < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :config
  scope :default_ip,  -> ()  { where(title: 'default-route-ip'.freeze).first }
  scope :term_sbc_ip, -> ()  { where(title: 'term-sbc-ips'.freeze).first }
end
```

---

```
describe 'Admins::Setting' do
   before(:each) do
     Admins::Setting.create(title: 'default-route-ip', config: '192.168.1.65')
     Admins::Setting.create(title: 'term-sbc-ips', config: "[{'192.168.1.79' => '104.197.17.91'},{'192.168.1.42' => '104.196.101.235'}]")
   end 

   describe '#term_sbc_ip' do
     context 'when terminating ip is not present' do
      it 'should return nil' do
        Admins::Setting.term_sbc_ip.destroy
        expect(Admins::Setting.term_sbc_ip).to eq(nil)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

---

When I run the following test I get the following error.

```
Failures:

  1) Admins::Setting#term_sbc_ip when terminating ip is not present should return nil
     Failure/Error: expect(Admins::Setting.term_sbc_ip).to eq(nil)

       expected: nil
            got: #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Admins::Setting id: 5, title: "default-route-ip", config: "192.168.1.65", created_at: "2017-12-26 11:38:03", updated_at: "2017-12-26 11:38:03">]>

       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/models/admins/setting_spec.rb:30:in `block in (root)
```

Note sure why when I delete the `term_sbc_ip` record the scope retrieve the `default-route-ip` object.

**Rspec Version**: `3.3.2`

**ActiveRecord**:

```
  activerecord (4.2.0)

  activerecord-jdbc-adapter (1.3.19)

  activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter (1.3.19)
```

**jruby**: `9.0.5.0`

**rails**: `No its not a rails application`

**postgres**: `9.5.9`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `scope` method in the Rails(ActiveRecord) always returns an array(AR collection), no matter what are you setting `.last` or `.first`.

```
scope :term_sbc_ip, ->  { where(title: 'term-sbc-ips'.freeze).first }
                                                             ^^^^^# not works
```

So your specs are wrong, here is how it must be written:

```
it 'should return an empty array' do
  record = Admins::Setting.term_sbc_ip.first
  record.destroy
  expect(Admins::Setting.term_sbc_ip).to eq([])
end
```

Comment: Umm, when I query the record it does work ```Admins::Setting.term_sbc_ip
=> #<Admins::Setting:0x5edacf20
 id: 2,
 title: "term-sbc-ips",
 config: "[{'192.168.1.79' => '104.197.17.91'},{'192.168.1.42' => '104.196.101.235'}]",
 created_at: "2017-12-26T12:01:11.808Z",
 updated_at: "2017-12-26T12:01:11.808Z">```

Comment: try without any record in the database, as in your tests, it returns an array, but you're expecting `nil`.